# Как можно поставить на сайте такой функционал?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

по аналогии как у яндекса еды можно выбрать свой адресс, хочется поставить такой же на сайт. Вопрос лишь в том каким образом можно поставить лишь поиск( без карты ) дабы он делал автодополнения?

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос, то например с помощью сервиса [DaData](https://dadata.ru/suggestions/) или реализовать свой на основе технологий и API Яндекса или Google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать сторонние сервисы при помощи API, например Dadata для авто дополнения адреса. У них существует ограничение на кол-во запросов в бесплатной версии 10к в день(если не изменяет память), на небольшой проект будет достаточно.